# Establishing socket connection in php using SOCKS Proxy

Tags: php, sockets, networking, socks

I am trying to establish a socket connection in php over a socks 4/5 proxy. How Can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have never written any proxy-able code in PHP, (I have in Perl), you need to use the proxy libraries to make your calls to the proxy server so they can be relayed to your destination.

Here is an article which discusses PHP proxying.
http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-php-client-library-through-proxy.html?m=1

Hope this helps.